# rendering react on server

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I've been trying to figure out how to render react on the server (node/express) and finally found a simple enough tutorial to understand what's going on. But now, after setting everything up, I'm getting an error in the `React.render` method:

here's my component file:

```
var React = require('react');
var box = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div style='padding: 10px'>
                this.props.text
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<box text='testing server side'/>, document.body);
module.exports = box;
```

I get an error when I run `npm start`:

> document is not defined

how do I get around this? do I need or not need the render method?

to give more context, this `box` component is being required by another component:

```
var React = require('react');
var Box = require('../react-jsx/box.js'); //this is the box component
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>
                        React Server Rendering
                    </title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <Box text='testing'/>
                    <script src="public/bundle.js"></script>
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Component;
```

and this is all being used in index.js

```
require('node-jsx').install();
var React = require('react');
var Component = require('../custom-modules/test-react-server-module.js');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/react', function(req, res, next) {
  var markup = React.renderToString(Component());
  res.send(markup);
});

module.exports = router;
```

and if I remove the render method I get this error in the browser:

> Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined

I saw some people saying that may be due to the jsx transformer being old, but I think I have the latest version

I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend update your React version. The current version exposes two different Top-Level API's: **React**, which is generally used to create components and **ReactDOM**, which exposes DOM-specific methods to be used at the top level of your app.

There is to things to point out here:

- You are trying to run an code that is supposed to be executed only at the browser. There is no **document** in NodeJS. I'd suggest using `webpack` to pack this component files and serve them on browser.
- For an isomorphic React application, you need to have a `client.js` file that calls the render function for the same component you are trying to render inside `index.js`. Got it?

Understand the `ReactDOM.render`, as the documentation states:

> Render a ReactElement into the DOM in the supplied container and return a reference to the component (or returns null for stateless components).
>
> If the ReactElement was previously rendered into container, this will 
>   perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to
>   reflect the latest React component.

**Keep in mind, again, that ReactDOM.render should be only used a few times and generally at the top level of your app, just one time.**

Having said this, your `box.js` should look like:

```
var React = require('react');
var box = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div style='padding: 10px'>
                this.props.text
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = box;
```

For this to properly work, you will need to create a main component `main-component-file.js`:

```
var React = require('react');
var Box = require('../react-jsx/box.js'); //this is the box component
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>
                        React Server Rendering
                    </title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <Box text='testing'/>
                    <script src="public/bundle.js"></script>
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Component;
```

Inside your `bundle.js` you need to make sure that this is being called so the main component tries to re-render:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Component = require('main-component-file.js'); 

ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.body);
```

At last but not least: `index.js`, the server file. Change `React.renderToString` to `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`, create a React Element from your main component and use it:

```
var element = React.createElement(Component)
router.get('/react', function(req, res, next) {
  var markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element);
  res.send(markup);
});
```

**Don't forget to include the npm package `react-dom/server` at your `index.js`.**

References used in the article:

- [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)
- [ReactDOM.render() docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render)
- [ReactDOMServer docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver)

Comment: hi thanks so much for the explanation. what package do I install with nom for react-dom/server? `npm install react-dom/server`?

Comment: ok got it. sorry one more question. so to use ReactDOM.render do I have to require another package as well? or i just require react and I can access reactDOM?

Comment: oh wait, probably the reactDom package that i just installed right?

Comment: lol sorry to bother you again but i'm still confused about one thing. when i exchange react.render to reactDOM.render, how is that supposed to look? do I remove the "document" reference?

Comment: As I mentioned on my answer, the ReactDOM.render should be called very few times. You should call the ReactDOM.render on the same component you are trying to render on the server. IMHO, you are calling at the wrong component. Maybe I should include this at my answer?

Comment: yes please that would be helpful! :) if you could fix any other wrong code I have and show me how to correct it because I still can't get the component to render on the client-side.

Comment: The point of the isomorphic react application is to use the same components to render at the server and to re-render at the client. So if you render ComponentA at server, on the client.js file that goes in your script tag should try to re-render Component A, also. It's clear now? :)

Comment: Updated since FB is now saying `React.createFactory()` is considered "legacy".

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createfactory

Works w/ `React.createElement()` directly in React 16

Answer (score 1):

You should delete this

```
React.render(<box text='testing server side'/>, document.body);
```

There is no need for it. What you are essentially telling React to do is render it right then and there.

`document.body` doesn't exist yet because you are rendering it server-side and you also don't need it because you render the component in the `renderToString` function upon request in the `router`. (Also I think @PeterLyons is correct so take a look at his answer too).

Also if you are strictly using React for views only, you might want to take a look at [express-react-views](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views). They have a good tutorial of how to use React with Express and you essentially can use it for server-side rendering only. I don't think it's as ideal as using `react-router` depending on what you're building but it illustrates how React is handling the server-side rendering and works with Express.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `react-dom/server` package's [renderToString](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring) function in the server environment. This will return the HTML as a string which you can send in your express response.

Comment: I see, could you maybe alter the relevant part of my code and show me what I have to do? or here's a question, do I just require the react-dom package in index.js?